# generate serial number in decreasing order given a variable in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

would like to find out the syntax in tableau, given column number, trying to generate rows for number in decreasing order down to 0.

Below is an example of what I'm trying to do

BEFORE

| ID | NUMBER |
| --- | --- |
| A | 4 |
| B | 5 |

AFTER

| ID | NUMBER |
| --- | --- |
| A | 4 |
| A | 3 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 1 |
| B | 5 |
| B | 4 |
| B | 3 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

If your Tableau version supports, try using ROWNUMBER with order by. Something like this:
{ ORDERBY [Your column]:ROW_NUMBER()}